# how to get the id of input type imagein in php

Tags: php, forms, image, types

my form has images as inputs so i used

there is no submit input because i used the image as submit
now i can get the image id

```html
<input type="image" src="my/source" name="Logo" />
```

i had tried to put hidden input but it returned all the ID's in the data not the selected one

Comment: Show us the whole `<form>.......</form>` block please

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, `<input type="image">` has a `src` attribute, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?
<input type="hidden" value="my/source" name="logo" /> when submitted will result in either $_GET['logo'] or if POSTed $_POST['logo']

Comment: @CBroe Woops I read it as `type="file"` What a doofus I am

Comment: @CBroe But shouldn't it be referencing a specific file not a directory? _Get me the instant expert :)_

Comment: <form method="POST">
     foreach($values as $value){
    <input type="image" src="my/source" name="$value['logo']" />
  <input name='id' type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" />
}</form>

Answer (score 1):

If you need to transport an actual value, then `<input type="image">` is not a good choice to begin with. The only info you will get in the form submission data set, is the click coordinates, under the parameter names `Logo.x` and `Logo.y` (with `name="Logo"`.)

You should use a `button` instead. That allows you to specify the submission value, and the image itself can be put *inside* the button, using a normal `img` element.

```
<button name="Logo" value="some_id_here"><img src="my/source"></button>
```

`type="submit"` is the default type for buttons, so it does not need to be put on there explicitly to make this a submit button.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you tell me what is the value is used for?

Comment: That’s were you put that image ID that you wanted to send to the server, when that particular button gets clicked to submit the form. (This replaces any hidden fields you tried to put IDs in then.)

Comment: okay but i want to get the ID of the its attribute , like if its name, i want to get the id of this name

Comment: What is “the id of a name” supposed to be? Do you mean, you _just_ want the image name? Well then put _that_ into the value attribute of the button then …

Comment: in the data there's company logo and company id okay, i put the logos as input to select from them,  i want to get the company's id of the selected logo

Comment: So put the company ID into the value attribute of the button then …